# vue-resource: Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

vue-resource:

```
Vue.http.post(API_URL + '/jwt/access_token', credentials, {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
        }, err => reject(err))
```

My api is properly configured with the CORS laravel..

I get that error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.app/jwt/access_token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Request headers:

```
OPTIONS /jwt/access_token HTTP/1.1
Host: finance.app
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

where I'm going wrong?  :(

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what about the response headers?

Comment: The problem was solved.
Was no setting in vue-resource, but a small middlware configuration error in laravel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set header in server side like this(if you are using PHP):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, x-requested-with, Authorization');
```

the key is line 2, means can access POST/GET/OPTIONS to request.

P.S. English is not my mother language hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to add these headers to PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

And following option to Vue, to pass post data to PHP:

```
Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true
```